# Given a string, what will be the rank of original string in the sorted (lexicographically) sequence of all it's unique substrings

Tags: string, algorithm

Given a string, what will be rank of original string in the sorted (lexicographically) sequence of all it's unique substrings.
example - abc
unique sorted sequence of substrings are - 
a,ab,abc,b,bc,c . So it's rank would be 3.
Is there a better method than generating all unique substrings and after sorting find it's rank. I used set stl for this question and got Time Limit Exceeded.

Comment: To make sure, what is the answer of "ABABA"? Is it 5?

Comment: Yes, it's rank will be 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, build a [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) of the given string.

For example, if the string is "ABABA", its suffix array `sa[]` and the height array `height[i]=LCP(sa[i],sa[i-1])` will be:

```
| i    | sa[i] | height[i] |
| ---- | ----- | --------- |
| 1    | A     | 0         |
| 2    | ABA   | 1         |
| 3    | ABABA | 3         |
| 4    | BABA  | 0         |
| 5    | BA    | 2         |
```

You can see every substring that is prior to `ABABA` is belong to a suffix prior than `ABABA` in the suffix array. For example:

- `A`, belongs to `sa[1]`.
- `A`, `AB` and `ABA` belong to `sa[2]`. But the first substring is repeated.
- `A`, `AB`, `ABA`, `ABAB`, `ABABA` belong to `sa[3]`. But the first 3 substrings are repeated.

So if the whole string is ranked #`n` in the suffix array, the answer will be:

`\sum_{i=1}^{n} length(sa[i]) - height[i]`

So the answer for "ABABA" is `1+3+5-1-3=5`.

You can have the whole source code for this problem [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25408624/). Not fully tested but it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Build [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) for given string

Make [longest common prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array) array for that suffix array

Count unique substrings before position of original string in suffix array